# Cannot connect to sqlserver when my android phone is connected to pc thorugh usb

Tags: android

I have been facing a problem from few days. I have created an android app which has a button. When button is clicked it should fetch data from sql server. I have given my IP for the connection string i.e. 192.168.x.x, this app is running successfully on emulator. But when i run the app from the samsung galaxy phone is does not get connected to sql server. This question has been posted many times and i have done lot of research on it but could not find proper answer. I m confused with connection string. Should i use 10.0.2.2 or 127.0.1.1 or my static ip. Thanks in advance for help. I will be grateful for the replies i get. Please do help me !!!

Comment: Are you using some kind of webservices to connect to sql server ?

Comment: The SQL server is running on the same computer that the emulator runs on?

Comment: Yes sir the Sql server and emulator both are on the same machine that is my machine. I am connecting the phone on my pc through usb

Comment: No sir there is no webservice i using jtds drivers for connection

Comment: Is the phone able to connect to same network as the PC using wifi?

Comment: I think that the phone is connected to the computer in a separate network from the one your computer use, try to connect the phone using wifi

Comment: Yes sir the phone is able to access the wifi which my pc uses. But sir what is the use of Wifi for this connection can you please explain i am not able to understand. Can it be done without wifi only through usb

Comment: Yes this is the actual problem which i am not able to understand. Can you please explain this point in detail

Comment: Can i do this task without involvement of WiFi??? I just want that when i connect phone through usb, it should find the sql server from my pc and fetch data from it

Comment: Can i do this task without involvement of WiFi??? I just want that when i connect phone through usb, it should find the sql server from my pc and fetch data from it

Comment: Yes i have switched on the wifi in my phone. The phone is able to access webservices which were used by another application and those are hosted on my pc. So i guess there is no problem with wifi because the phone is in the LAN. I dont realize where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your phone USB connection is used to :
-Share phone connection with computer
-transfer some informations between the phone and the computer
...
But to connect to your sql server ( hosted in the computer ) you must have the two devices computer and phone on the same network

What you are doing is trying to connect over the wifi network by 192.168.x.x

Check you network properties to see what's the ip for your computer in the USB-phone-computer network not in the wifi network

Comment: ok and how can i do that?? i mean from where do i get to know the ip in the usb-phone-computer network.

Comment: If it's windows 7 you can see the network and sharing center for the existing networks or type ipconfig in the cmd window, and for unix based you can user the ifconfig cmd

Answer (score 0):

Add `import android.util.Log;` to the top of your code and change the line in your catch statement from `e1.getMessage();` to `Log.e("DBDebug", e1.getMessage());`

Then run this code on the phone again with the USB cable attached. If you are using the ADT with eclipse, add a tag filter to the logcat window as "DBDebug". This will show all of the debugging messages for your app and will catch any error messages. Look through that and see if there's any errors reported from jdbc.

Or, if you're using the android tools from the console, the command is `adb logcat -s "DBDebug"`

It is possible to create a network between an android device and PC using the USB cable, but that is a lot more complicated than just using the pre-existing network that is already working by connecting your phone to the WiFi.

On the computer that the SQL server is running, open a command window/console and type 'ipconfig'. You will see something similar to this. The line reading IPv4 address is the IP address your android application will use to connect to the SQL server.

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e4f4:7f27:bb97:ac87%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.7
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

You will also need to ensure there is no firewall blocking connections over the network to your SQL server.

Depending on how your SQL server is set up, it may only allow access from localhost rather than across the network. Ensure that you have configured a user within the SQL server and aren't trying to connect as the root user. Default SQL users often only allow localhost connections for security reasons. I believe this could be what your problem is, you need to create a user that is able to access the server over the network.

If you are using MySQL the syntax would be something similar to this:

```
CREATE USER 'david'@'192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0';
```

If for example your network is in the 192.168.1.xxx range, you would change the above line to reflect that.

Comment: I wrote ipconfig in cmd, i got the output like the one you have shown above. There was no IPV4 address. Instead there was IP Address : 192.168.x.x and this is the one i m using in the code which i have posted below

Answer (score 0):

This is my code which i m using. I have a database SysTestNew. I am importing parties from the table and adding them in my sqlite database. I m calling the importdata() on my button. This works well in emulator but not on my samsung phone.

```
String userName = "xxxxxx";
String password = "xxxxx";
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.x.x:1433/SysTestNEW";
Connection conn;
String ACCODE, ACC_DESC, Address, Phone, Mobile, Area_Code, AREA_DESC,
        ItemCode, ItemDesc, itemgroup_code, ITEMSUBGRP, unit, SaleRate,
        getsalesmanname, getareaval, getgrpval;
DatabaseOperations db = new DatabaseOperations(this);
Button btnback, btnimport, btnimportitem;
Spinner spinareaname, spinitemname;
CheckBox chkareaall, chkitemall;


public void importdata() {

    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection open",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet reset;

        if (!chkareaall.isChecked()) {
            getareaval = spinareaname.getSelectedItem().toString();
            reset = stmt
                    .executeQuery("select am.ACCODE,am.ACC_DESC,cm.Address,cm.Phone,cm.Mobile,cm.Area_Code,ar.AREA_DESC from ACCMASTER am left join Custmaster cm on am.ACCODE=cm.Accode left join AREA ar on cm.Area_Code = ar.AREA_CODE where am.GROUP_ID='DR' and ar.AREA_DESC='"
                            + getareaval + "'");
        } else {
            reset = stmt
                    .executeQuery("select am.ACCODE,am.ACC_DESC,cm.Address,cm.Phone,cm.Mobile,cm.Area_Code,ar.AREA_DESC from ACCMASTER am left join Custmaster cm on am.ACCODE=cm.Accode left join AREA ar on cm.Area_Code = ar.AREA_CODE where am.GROUP_ID='DR'");
        }

        if (reset != null) {
            while (reset.next()) {
                ACCODE = reset.getString(1);
                ACC_DESC = reset.getString(2);
                Address = reset.getString(3);
                Phone = reset.getString(4);
                Mobile = reset.getString(5);
                Area_Code = reset.getString(6);
                AREA_DESC = reset.getString(7);
                db.insertCustomer(ACCODE, ACC_DESC, Address, Phone, Mobile,
                        Area_Code, AREA_DESC);
            }
            alertdialogbox("Import Parties",
                    "Parties Imported Successfully !!");
        }

        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: See my updated answer on how you would go about printing error messages to the log.

Comment: Ok i will try the log method. And sir today i checked once again that the phone is getting connected to the LAN. And do i need to do reverse tethering for this?? I did some research and found this. Will it help or i can do without it??

Comment: No, tethering is irrelevant. We're trying to get it to work over your LAN. Reverse tethering would complicate things even more because it is more difficult to set up and introduces another factor of uncertainty.

Comment: Ok thank you for this advice. I will find out the error from log cat and i'll let you know.

Comment: You already know the code is working as it worked in the emulator. The way I see it, this is either a problem with the networking (wrong IP, firewall in the way) or a problem with the way the users are set up on the SQL server. The error messages should tell us more.

Comment: Ya exactly. Firewall is kept as on in my pc. What problem can a firewall create??

Comment: Firewalls are designed to block connections from other devices to prevent hackers etc... Your firewall could be blocking your phone from connecting to the SQL server port on your PC.

Comment: Ok i found the actual problem today. The connection to sql server is working properly in phones of android version 2.2 but when i test it on 4.0 and 4.1 i get the error of Networkonmainthread exception. So after googling i got the solution of using the AsyncTask class. Now when i fetch 15 to 20 records there is no exception but when i fetch 3000 to 5000 records i get the error of Networkonmainthread exception. So when there are bulk  of records it gives exception. So what is the solution to this problem. can you please help

Comment: @DavidHewitt can you please help with this problem

Answer (score 0):

My phone has a setting as "USB Tethering". I read somewhere that this setting is used when you want to connect your phone with your pc via wifi. I enabled this setting and then run my app but got no results... Is this setting or any other setting playing a role in connecting my phone to pc's wifi??